# Why is my sort function doing the job incorectly?

Tags: java, eclipse

Aparently, when i do the sort with only parametrized objects it preforms flawlessly, yet when i add the ones that don't have data, it just goes nuts. Help.

Btw, i want the data in falling order sorted by the "Stanje na racunu", or in english "your account balance", which takes the "stanje" variable in the object class and compares it. I'll repeat once more. This works flawlessly when tr1, tr2 and tr3 are not included. Help

```
    public class Glavna {
    
    public static void sort(TekuciRacun[] racuni) {
        TekuciRacun heljp = new TekuciRacun();
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < racuni.length - 1; i++)
            for ( int j = 1; j < racuni.length; j++)
                if ( racuni[i].getStanje() > racuni[j].getStanje() ) {
                    heljp = racuni[i];
                    racuni[i] = racuni[j];
                    racuni[j] = heljp;
                }
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < racuni.length; i++)
            System.out.println("\n" + racuni[i].toString());
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TekuciRacun ptr1 = new TekuciRacun("Marko Sisovic", 29381024, 20000, 15000, 0, -10000);
        TekuciRacun ptr2 = new TekuciRacun("Petar Gojkovic", 12341234, 25000, 10000, 5000, -15000);
        TekuciRacun ptr3 = new TekuciRacun("Milojko Marivic", 23455423, 30000, 20000, 15000, -30000);
        
        TekuciRacun tr1 = new TekuciRacun();
        TekuciRacun tr2 = new TekuciRacun();
        TekuciRacun tr3 = new TekuciRacun();
        
        TekuciRacun[] racuni = { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, tr1, tr2, tr3};
        
        sort(racuni);
    }
}
```

Here's the result.

```
Ime i prezime vlasnika: Milojko Marivic
Broj racuna: 23455423
Stanje na racunu: -5000 dinara <====this is the data that's used for sorting
Dozvoljen minus: -30000 dinara

Ime i prezime vlasnika: Petar Gojkovic
Broj racuna: 12341234
Stanje na racunu: 10000 dinara <====
Dozvoljen minus: -15000 dinara

Ime i prezime vlasnika: Marko Sisovic
Broj racuna: 29381024
Stanje na racunu: 5000 dinara <====
Dozvoljen minus: -10000 dinara

Ime i prezime vlasnika: null
Broj racuna: 0
Stanje na racunu: 0 dinara 
Dozvoljen minus: 0 dinara

Ime i prezime vlasnika: null
Broj racuna: 0
Stanje na racunu: 0 dinara 
Dozvoljen minus: 0 dinara

Ime i prezime vlasnika: null
Broj racuna: 0
Stanje na racunu: 0 dinara 
Dozvoljen minus: 0 dinara
```

```
    public class TekuciRacun implements IRacun{
    private String vlasnik;
    private int brojRacuna;
    private int uplate;
    private int isplate;
    private int kredit;
    private int dozvoljenMinus;
    private int stanje = 0;
    
    TekuciRacun(){
        
    }
    
    TekuciRacun (String vlasnik, int brojRacuna, int uplate, int isplate, int kredit, int dozvoljenMinus){
        super();
        this.vlasnik = vlasnik;
        this.brojRacuna = brojRacuna;
        this.uplate = uplate;
        this.isplate = isplate;
        this.kredit = kredit;
        this.dozvoljenMinus = dozvoljenMinus;
        
        this.stanje = stanje(uplate, isplate, kredit);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int stanje(int uplate, int isplate, int kredit) {
        return stanje = uplate - isplate - kredit;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ime i prezime vlasnika: " + vlasnik 
                + "\nBroj racuna: " + brojRacuna
                + "\nStanje na racunu: " + stanje(uplate, isplate, kredit)
                + " dinara \nDozvoljen minus: " + dozvoljenMinus
                + " dinara\nKredit: " + kredit;
    }

    public String getVlasnik() {
        return vlasnik;
    }

    public int getBrojRacuna() {
        return brojRacuna;
    }

    public int getUplate() {
        return uplate;
    }

    public int getIsplate() {
        return isplate;
    }

    public int getKredit() {
        return kredit;
    }

    public int getDozvoljenMinus() {
        return dozvoljenMinus;
    }

    public int getStanje() {
        return stanje;
    }

    public void setVlasnik(String vlasnik) {
        this.vlasnik = vlasnik;
    }

    public void setBrojRacuna(int brojRacuna) {
        this.brojRacuna = brojRacuna;
    }

    public void setUplate(int uplate) {
        this.uplate = uplate;
    }

    public void setIsplate(int isplate) {
        this.isplate = isplate;
    }

    public void setKredit(int kredit) {
        this.kredit = kredit;
    }

    public void setDozvoljenMinus(int dozvoljenMinus) {
        this.dozvoljenMinus = dozvoljenMinus;
    }

    public void setStanje(int stanje) {
        this.stanje = stanje;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

The desired output is (not the full, only the names(vlasnik))

1. Petar Gojkovic
2. Marko Sisovic
3. Milojko Marivic
4. null
5. null
6. null

Edit.
After debugging(adding a println between the two for loops) i can see that after the first "i" iteration the result is perfect, but, the loop keeps going, as it should, but starts doing something it shouldn't do. I guess this is out of bounds of my knowledge since i guess this is some compiler "problem".

Comment: Use the `Arrays.sort()` method. Unless you have a really good reason not to, such as a homework assignment that requires you to implement your own sort. If this is a homework assignment, then you need to thoroughly understand standard sorting algorithms such as bubble sort and quick sort in order to implement one of them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , yes, 1) this is college assighments, 2) even if i could use it i wouldn't since i don't know how, and i find this way much more easier, although when i searched through the web for answers i realized that bubble is the least efficient way of them all, so i'll be working to learn new things. Thank you for being helpfull, you really did a lot to make my knowledge grow. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243898/discussion-on-question-by-marko-why-is-my-sort-function-doing-the-job-incorectly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop logic is incorrect. To do a proper sort, the inside loop (`j`) has to start from the current `i+1` upward. Instead, it starts from 1 every time. When you only have 3 elements, you may not see the problem.

Basically, it compares elements from the area that was already sorted with elements in the unsorted area.

Comment: 6hours of brain storming and scanning the internet for this...i feel sad...but thankfull. Thank you @RealSkeptic Just tell me, did you see the mistake at the first glance and decided to let me figure it out or you had to give it a second look?

Comment: @Marko Alternatively, you could compare the `j`th element with the `(j+1)`th element, rather than `i`th and `j`th elements.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've never thought of that, i'll try :)

Comment: No, @Marko, I didn't see this immediately. That's why I needed to see your expected output, and edited your question to properly format your output, to understand where you even saw a problem.